# Using regex to match any character except =

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to write a String validation to match any character (regular, digit and special) except =.

Here is what I have written -

```
    String patternString = "[[^=][\\w\\s\\W]]*";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(patternString);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(str);

    if(m.matches())
        System.out.println("matches");
    else
        System.out.println("does not");
```

But, it matches the input string "2009-09/09 12:23:12.5=" with the pattern.

How can I exclude = (or any other character, for that matter) from the pattern string?

Comment: What are you trying to match? (or not)? just [^=]* will match anything but the '=' char.

Comment: You cannot nest character classes. `[[]` is simply a character class consisting of the single character `[`.

Comment: `[^=]*` regex pattern will match any character except `=`

Answer (score 120):

If the only prohibited character is the equals sign, something like `[^=]*` should work.

`[^...]` is a negated character class; it matches a single character which is any character except one from the list between the square brackets. `*` repeats the expression zero or more times.

Comment: How can I make `[^=]*` match `\n`, as well?

Comment: Not a Java person, but my first search engine match was https://stackoverflow.com/a/30315738/874188

Comment: Hmm thanks, but my particular use case is search-and-replace in VSCode.

Comment: @CameronHudson Just had the same problem and using alternation worked for me: `([^=]|[\n])*`

Answer (score 12):

First of all, you don't need a regexp. Simply call [`contains`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)):

```
if(str.contains("="))
    System.out.println("does not");
else
    System.out.println("matches");
```

The correct regexp you're looking for is just

```
String patternString = "[^=]*";
```

Comment: This may be very helpful for the original poster.  But this answer is very far from the specific text of the question, which leads thousands of others to this page.  This alternative has much less value for them.

Answer (score 9):

If your goal is to not have any = characters in your string, please try the following

```
String patternString = "[^=]*";
```

Answer (score 3):

If you only want to check for occurence of "=" why don't you use the String indexOf() method?

```
if str.indexOf('=')  //...
```

Comment: `contains` is shorter, easier to understand, and you don't need to fiddle around with indices.