# extract only certain tags in xml file using pig latin

Tags: apache-pig

I want to extract only the states from the below xml file.

<.Table>

```
 <State>Florida</State>

 <id>123</id>
```

<./Table>

<.Table>

```
 <State>Texas</State>

 <id>456</id>
```

<./Table>

- Expected output :

  (Florida)

  (Texas)

But with the below pig statements I get

()

() as output

A = LOAD 'hdfs:/user.xml' USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.XMLLoader('Table') 
AS (x:chararray);

B = FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN (REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(x,

```
'<Table>\\n\\s*<State>(.*)</State>\\n\\s*\\n\\s*</Table>')) 

as (state:chararray);
```

Please help me understand where I have gone wrong or how do I eliminate a certain tag line?

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a buggy regex, after the closing `</State>` you are using `\\n\\s*\\n\\s*</Table>` which seems to ignore the the `<id>...</id>` elements.  Have you looked at using some XML parsing library in a UDF?  It might be easier than trying to build a bunch of regexes by hand.

EDIT: One other suggestion.  Are you sure that the line separators in your file are just `\n`, you may have `\r\n` as the separator, in which case `[\r\n]+` should help see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3445326/regex-in-java-problem-with-newline) for more details.