# Simple regex working on Windows and not in Linux using Java

Tags: java, regex

Using Eclipse under windows I'm trying to split a text in two parts, the one from the start until the first line break and the rest of it

```
String[] result = resumen.split("\\R", 2);
String firstpart = result[0];
String rest = result[1];
```

Works ok.

But on a Linux machine I'm getting the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal/unsupported escape sequence near index 1
\R
```

So I read somewhere on SO that I can use:

```
String[] result = resumen.split("\\\\R", 2);
```

But this does not work as expect and it doesnt split the sentence.

How can I adapt the code so it can work on a linux machine too?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also see [*RegEx in Java: how to deal with newline*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3445417/3832970).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds to me like the Linux machine has an older version of Java, and `\R` was added after that version.

`\R` is in [Java 8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html). It's not in [Java 7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

If you need to support Java 7, the docs say `\R` is equivalent to `\u000D\u000A|[\u000A\u000B\u000C\u000D\u0085\u2028\u2029]`.

So based on that:

```
String[] result = resumen.split("\\u000D\\u000A|[\\u000A\\u000B\\u000C\\u000D\\u0085\\u2028\\u2029]", 2);
```

but I think we're okay if we supply those characters to the regex engine as literal characters rather than unicode escapes, so:

```
String[] result = resumen.split("\u000D\u000A|[\u000A\u000B\u000C\u000D\u0085\u2028\u2029]", 2);
```

(but test that.)

Comment: @XtremeBaumer: Not if the goal is to match line breaks cross-platform.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer: Windows, but it's not so much platform as string contents. If you have a string with Windows-style linebreaks in it, splitting on `\n` will leave the `\r` in the resulting strings. And looking at the `\R` equivalent, there are more exotic line breaks as well.

Comment: how come if i read a textfile with 2 lines and use `System.out.print(line);` i don't get 2 lines as output?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer: It depends on how you're reading the file; sounds like line breaks were normalized. But again, it's about string contents. `"foo\r\nbar".split("\\n")[0].length()` is 4, not 3. `"foo\r\nbar".split("\\R")[0].length()` is 3 as desired.

Comment: Why not using `System.getProperty("line.separator")` to get the right newline character?